# how to add optirun to vscode debug options?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython, nvidia, manjaro

I use manjaro and want to use vscode tool for debug my python program,but i use CUDA, so i usually use a command like this:

```
optirun ipython program.py arg1 arg2
```

when i try to debug the program optirun isn't called, so i don't have access to GPU, how can i call optirun before python (or ipython)?

I've tried to change settins.json and launch.json to add it to command but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did and it worked.

1. Make a bash script, name it anything, assume `script.sh`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

optirun python "$@"
```

2. In `.vscode/launch.json` set `"pythonPath"` to `./script.sh`.
   Here is a example `launch.json`

```js
{
   // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
   // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
   // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [


       {
           "name": "Python: Current File",
           "type": "python",
           "request": "launch",
           "program": "${file}",
           "console": "integratedTerminal",
           "linux": {
               "pythonPath": "./script.sh"
           },
       }
   ]
}
```

3. Now it should work as intended.

I also faced the same problem while debugging a OpenCL application in python. My Nvidia graphics card was managed by optirun. `$@` passes all the command line arguments supplied by vscode to the python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You could try editing your `launch.json` to point to `optirun` as your Python interpreter via the [`"python.pythonPath"` setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_pythonpath).